# Rename multiple files adding a unique string

Tags: windows, command-line, rename

I am using Windows XP operating system, I have a folder with multiple files, e.g.:

- `ERHS 34334.jpg`
- `ERHS 12123.jpg`
- `ERHS 98484.jpg`

I want to rename all those files at once as like below:

- `ERHS 34334_thumb.jpg`
- `ERHS 12123_thumb.jpg`
- `ERHS 98484_thumb.jpg`

Existing name should not change; I want to add some unique string to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Command Prompt:

```
for %f in (ERHS*.jpg) do ren "%f" "%~nf_thumb.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
Dir ERHS*.jpg | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace ".jpg", "_thumb.jpg" }
```

You might need to install PowerShell for Windows XP beforehand.